# How to check raw data from one workbook against a master list in another workbook

Tags: windows, excel, vba

I am new to VBA-Excel and need some help. I have one workbook that contains a master list of acceptable string values. This workbook is updated regularly. I have another workbook that contains all raw data. I want to have my macro open the master list, check each entry from the second column in my raw data against the master list and delete any cells that are not contained in my master list. I need some pointers to set me on my way. Here is what I have so far:

Sub Firstcheck()

```
Dim wkb As Object
Dim wkbname As Object
Dim masterlist As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set wkbname = ActiveWorkbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="T:\Communications and Media\Media\Media    Reporting\media master list.xlsx")
wkb.Activate
Set masterlist = Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown))

wkbname.Activate
Range("a1").Select
For i = 1 To 3
If Len(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) > 1 Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    For Each cell In masterlist.Cells
        If cell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        Exit For


        Else: ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4

        End If

        Next cell


Else: i = 10
End If
i = i - 1
Next

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: @sirentec I wasn't able to figure out how to use public cell and public string, but I was able to write a working program. The only thing is excel often freezes when I run it. I have edited the program above to contain the new code.

Answer (score 0):

This is without the Excel parts, but how about something like this...

```
    public class CellValue
    {
        public string theValue { get; set; }
    }

    List<CellValue> masterList = new List<CellValue>(); //Load these values into the list
    List<CellValue> otherList = new List<CellValue>();   //Load these values into the list

    List<string> onesToDelete = otherList.Select(x => !masterList.Any(x2 => x2.theValue == x.theValue));
```

Comment: wow, I don't understand that at all. I will have to go read up on public class and public string. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, you can try this:

```
Sub Firstcheck()
    Dim cel As Range, masterList
    With Workbooks.Open("T:\Communications and Media\Media\Media    Reporting\media master list.xlsx")
        With .Worksheets(1)
            masterList = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).value2
        End With
        .Close False
    End With

    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(2).Cells
        If IsError(Application.match(Trim(cel.value2)), masterList) Then
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Else
            cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That was perfect. I really appreciate it.